# How do I add an OR condition inside a GraphQl where statement by graphql version is 16.5.0?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, graphql-js

I cannot get a WHERE statement working with an 'OR' condition in react-typescript.

I would like to return all results where either the 'title' OR 'content' fields contain the search_text.

**I have tried the following: **

```
articles(where: { 
or: [
  { "title_contains" : "search_text"},
  {"content_contains" : "search_text"}
 ]
}) {
title
content
};
```

};`

Comment: what are you using for GraphQL backend?

Comment: For Backend I'm using MongoDb